# How to find the column space $C(A)$ for a given matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let's say I have the following matrix $A$:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and I row reduce it to $A'$:

$$A' = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Correct me if I'm wrong, but elementary row operations show us if the rows are linearly dependant/independant, not if the columns are linearly dependant/independant. They don't affect the row space $R(A)$. but they do change the column space $C(A)$.

$C(A) = \left\{\lambda \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} \ni \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ whereas $C(A') = \left\{\lambda \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} \ni \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

Now since elementary row operations change the columns space $C(A)$, how can we find the linearly independent columns of $A$ and express $C(A)$ as linear combinations of those linearly independent columns?

Would we have to revert to elementary column operations *(if there is such a thing I've never seen it before)*, to *column reduce* $A$ and find it's linearly independent columns?

Furthermore, what is the best way/method to find the columns space $C(A)$? Is it better to find the linearly independent columns and express $C(A)$ in terms of those, or do you just take the linear combinations of all the columns, and simplify from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a basis for the column space by performing row operations.

After you obtain the row-echelon form, note down those columns that are pivotal columns.

Look at the original matrix, those columns should be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

### Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra

A matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ induces for fundamental subspaces:
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

---

### Reduced row echelon forms

Perhaps we can sort things out by looking at a close variation of this problem on a matrix which is not square:
$$
  \mathbf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Row space**

$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
& \mapsto
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{E_{A}} & \mathbf{R} \\
\end{array}
\right] \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
& \mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|rr}
 \boxed{1} & 1 & 1 & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The boxed pivot marks the sole fundamental column.

The subspace decomposition for the *row space* is
$$
 \mathbb{C}^{2} = 
 \mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) \oplus
 \mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) =
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  1 \\ 1 
\end{array} \right]}
\, \right\}
\oplus
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{red}{\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  -1 \\ 1 
\end{array} \right]}
\, \right\}
$$

**Column space**

$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{A^{*}} & \mathbf{I}_{3} \\
\end{array}
\right]
& \mapsto
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{E_{A}^{*}} & \mathbf{R} \\
\end{array}
\right] \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
& \mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|rrc}
 \boxed{1} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} \\
 0 & 0 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The boxed pivot marks the sole fundamental column.

The subspace decomposition for the *column space* is
$$
 \mathbb{C}^{3} = 
 \mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) \oplus
 \mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) =
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]}
\, \right\}
\oplus
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{red}{\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  -1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{array} \right]}, 
%
\,
\color{red}{\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]}
\, \right\}
$$

---

One way to find spans for the subspaces is to use...

### Singular value decomposition

The power of the SVD is that it provides orthonormal spans for all subspaces.

Every matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$$
has a singular value decomposition

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The column vectors are orthonormal basis vectors:
$$
\begin{align} 
% R A
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{u_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{u_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% R A*
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{v_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{v_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% N A*
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{u_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{u_{m}}
\right\} \\
% N A
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{v_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{v_{n}}
\right\} \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The decomposition distinctly reflects the reduction operations:
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
&=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{1\times 1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} &  
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]^{*}  \\
%
&=
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 \color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{-1} \\
 \color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c|cc}
 \sqrt{6} & 0 & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
% c1
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array}
\right]}
% c2
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right]}
% c3
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array}
\right]}
%
\end{array}
\right]^{*}
%
\end{align}
%
$$

Answer (score 0):

The columns of $A$ are the rows of $A^T$. If you are uncomfortable with column operations, you can row-reduce $A^T$ to a matrix $B$ and then transpose back.